# Openstack Cloud

Tags: cloud, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I want to deploy an openstack cloud that is highly available, can I use Ubuntu software for free or do I have to pay an license fee for the software.

My understanding is that that I can use the software but I buy an support contract separately is this correct?

If I use the autopilot for openstack - maas,juju and landscape - is there a node restriction?

Answer (score 2):

There is a license restriction, Landscape managed machines (real, or virtual) require licenses.  A managed machine is one on which the landscape-client is installed, and registered with the server.  So long as you don't register any other machines in it, Landscape Dedicated Server ships now with enough free licenses to build a simple cloud utilising 10 machines, but if you plan to put a decent sized cloud into production that way you're going to need to buy more Landscape licenses, which come as part of the Ubuntu Advantage product.

Answer (score 0):

The Beta of the OpenStack Autopilot can deploy on up to 10 physical nodes before running into the limits of its built-in license.

To be clear, the 10 free nodes will continue to be available even after the Beta period ends.

Finally, the current Beta does not support HA yet.